# Multi level nesting for multi pie chart interactive using D3

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am new to d3 and would like to create an interactive pie chart. I am able to draw the different pies but I am having trouble getting the individual cost by function name to show up on the pie when I mouseover.  I receive an undefined when I try to display the d.data.functionCost.

This is what I have accomplished so far....

[image]

I used d3.nest to nest the totals of each year and capture all the individual function name totals by year using d3.nest below

```
var donut_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.projectdate; })
    .key(function(d){return d.FunctionName; })
    .rollup(function(d){
      return { 'functionCost': d3.sum(d, function(c){
            return +c.Cost;
          })
        }
     })
    .entries(vmData)
    .map(function(group){
      var total = 0;
      group.values.forEach(function(d){
        total += d.values.functionCost;
      })
      return {
        'FiscalYear': group.key,
        'yearCost': total,
        'data': group.values.map(function(v){
          // console.log(v.values.functionCost);
          return {
            'FunctionName': v.key,
            'functionCost': v.values.functionCost
          }
        })
       };
    });

    return donut_data;
}
```

[image]

This is the part that should display the function cost.  The value is undefined and percentage is NaN. I think it has to do with d.data.functionCost not knowing what the index of d.data is but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
var eventObj = {

            'mouseover': function(d, i, j) {
                pathAnim(d3.select(this), 1);
                var thisDonut = charts.select('.type' + j);
                // console.log (thisDonut);
                thisDonut.select('.value').text(function(d, i) {
                    return '$' + d.data.functionCost;
                });
                thisDonut.select('.percentage').text(function(d,i) {

                    return (d.data.functionCost/d.yearCost*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
                });
            },
```